# Genesis file issue

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, quorum

My quorum server that uses a `geth` command to initiate a node is throwing this error:

> Fatal: invalid genesis file: missing required field 'balance' for
>   GenesisAccount

Geth version : 1.7.2-stable. Genesis file follow next.

```
 {
  "alloc": {
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000020": {
      "code": "0x606060405236156100c45760e060020a6000350",
      "storage": {
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001": "0x02",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002": "0x04",
        "0x29ecdbdf95c7f6ceec92d6150c697aa14abeb0f8595dd58d808842ea237d8494": "0x01",
        "0x6aa118c6537572d8b515a9f9154be55a3377a8de7991cd23bf6e5ceb368688e3": "0x01",
        "0x50793743212c6f01d326957d7069005b912f8215f10c7536be6b10782c6c44cd": "0x01",
        "0x38f6c908c5cc7ca668cec2f476abe61b4dbb1df20f0ad8e07ef5dbf6a2f1ffd4": "0x01",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004": "0x02",
        "0xaca3b76ed4968740c3180dd7fa37f4aa229a2c758a848f53920e9ccb4c4bb74e": "0x01",
        "0xd188ba2dc293670542c1befaf7678b0859e5354a0727d1188b2afb6f47fe24d1": "0x01"
      }

    },
    "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0xca843569e3427144cead5e4d5999a3d0ccf92b8e": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x0fbdc686b912d7722dc86510934589e0aaf3b55a": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x9186eb3d20cbd1f5f992a950d808c4495153abd5": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x0638e1574728b6d862dd5d3a3e0942c3be47d996": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "config": {
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "chainId": 1,
    "eip155Block": null,
    "eip158Block": null,
    "isQuorum": true
  },
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x",
  "gasLimit": "0x2FEFD800",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `"balance": "0"` for your preloaded contract?

Comment: Yes Adam i added a good big amount in the balance of pre loaded contract and it fixed the issue. Thanks a ton.